# How to reduce full sine wave LUT to a singe sine quadrant?

Tags: verilog, frequency, sine

I have implemented a full sine wave LUT, but would prefer to reduce it to a quarter.

````
module functionGenerator(Clk,data_out, freq);
//declare input and output
    input [7:0] freq;
    input Clk;
    output [9:0] data_out;
//declare the sine ROM - 30 registers each 8 bit wide.  
    reg [9:0] sine [0:99];
//Internal signals  
    integer i;  
    reg [9:0] data_out;
//Initialize the sine rom with samples. 
    initial begin
        i = 0;
        sine[0] = 0;        sine[1] = 10;        sine[2] = 20;        sine[3] = 29;        sine[4] = 39;   
        sine[5] = 48;       sine[6] = 58;        sine[7] = 67;        sine[8] = 75;        sine[9] = 84;
        sine[10] = 92;      sine[11] = 100;      sine[12] = 107;      sine[13] = 114;      sine[14] = 120;
        sine[15] = 126;     sine[16] = 132;      sine[17] = 137;      sine[18] = 141;      sine[19] = 145;   
        sine[20] = 149;     sine[21] = 151;      sine[22] = 153;      sine[23] = 155;      sine[24] = 156;
        sine[25] = 156;     sine[26] = 156;      sine[27] = 155;      sine[28] = 153;      sine[29] = 151;
        sine[30] = 149;     sine[31] = 145;      sine[32] = 141;      sine[33] = 137;      sine[34] = 132;   
        sine[35] = 126;     sine[36] = 120;      sine[37] = 114;      sine[38] = 107;      sine[39] = 100;
        sine[40] = 92;      sine[41] = 84;       sine[42] = 75;       sine[43] = 67;       sine[44] = 58;
        sine[45] = 48;      sine[46] = 39;       sine[47] = 29;       sine[48] = 20;       sine[49] = 10;   
        sine[50] = 0;       sine[51] = -10;      sine[52] = -20;      sine[53] = -29;      sine[54] = -39;
        sine[55] = -48;     sine[56] = -58;      sine[57] = -67;      sine[58] = -75;      sine[59] = -84;
        sine[60] = -92;     sine[61] = -100;     sine[62] = -107;     sine[63] = -114;     sine[64] = -120;   
        sine[65] = -126;    sine[66] = -132;     sine[67] = -137;     sine[68] = -141;     sine[69] = -145;
        sine[70] = -149;    sine[71] = -151;     sine[72] = -153;     sine[73] = -155;     sine[74] = -156;
        sine[75] = -156;    sine[76] = -156;     sine[77] = -155;     sine[78] = -153;     sine[79] = -151;   
        sine[80] = -149;    sine[81] = -145;     sine[82] = -141;     sine[83] = -137;     sine[84] = -132;
        sine[85] = -126;    sine[86] = -120;     sine[87] = -114;     sine[88] = -107;     sine[89] = -100;
        sine[90] = -92;     sine[91] = -84;      sine[92] = -75;      sine[93] = -67;      sine[94] = -58;
        sine[95] = -48;     sine[96] = -39;      sine[97] = -29;      sine[98] = -20;      sine[99] = -10;
    end

    //At every positive edge of the clock, output a sine wave sample.
    always@ (posedge(Clk))
    begin
        data_out = sine[i];
        i = i+ 1;
        if(i == 99)
            i = 0;
    end

endmodule
```
````

Comment: Maybe consider two separate LUTs? One handling from \$0\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}\$ and the other \$\frac{\pi}{2}\rightarrow\pi\$. (Obviously, there are finer symmetries, though.) The sine output takes its input from the first LUT. The cosine output takes its input from the second LUT. The two LUTs allow separate indexing and promises every quadrature combination never indexes into one LUT. But I'm sure someone has created a verilog code generator for this purpose. Have you looked around, at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of the symmetry of a sine wave:

```
if ( i < 25 )
   data_out = sine[i];
else if ( i < 50 )
   data_out = sine[50 - i];
else if  ( i < 75 )
   data_out = - sine[i - 50];
else 
   data_out = - sine[100 - i];
```

Answer (score 1):

For \$\pi < x < 2\pi\$,   sin(x) = -sin(x-\$\pi\$)

For \$\pi/2 < x < \pi\$, sin(x) = sin(\$\pi\$-x)

That reduces it down to \$0 < x < \pi/2\$  or a single quadrant, in which all the numbers will be positive and monotonic increasing.

Comment: Yes, but i need to produce a verilog code for that to implement it. I understand the concept, but not the appropriate syntax to do do so.